# When input[name="status"] is checked and has value 'no' && input[name="owner"] is not checked then add Class else remove Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a situation when `input[name="status"]` is checked and has the value 'no' && `input[name="owner"]` is empty then it is adding the class `error-highlight` else removing it.

It is working fine when the user selects the first 'no' option then it triggers the error class. But the issue is when the user selects an option in `input[name="owner"]` first and then selects the 'no' option in `input[name="status"]`. It triggers the error class again even though the other input has already been checked and is not empty. This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectStatus').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == 'no') {
      $('.selectOwner').addClass('error-higlight');
    } else {
      $('.selectOwner').removeClass('error-higlight');
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectOwner').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected != '') {
      $('.selectOwner').removeClass('error-higlight');
    } else {
      $('.selectOwner').addClass('error-higlight');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error-higlight {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217, 83, 80, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217, 83, 80, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217, 83, 80, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field text-left">
  <label for="owner1" class="text-left owner">
        <input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" />
         <span class="overlay-color"></span>Working</label>
</div>
<div class="field text-left">
  <label for="owner2" class="text-left owner">
        <input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" />
         <span class="overlay-color"></span>Jobless</label>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
  <label for="Yes" class="text-left">Yes</label>
  <input class="selectStatus" name="status" id="Yes" type="radio" value="yes" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <label for="No" class="text-left">No</label>
  <input class="selectStatus" name="status" id="No" type="radio" value="no" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a check to see if `owner` is `undefined` or not while changing status  like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectStatus').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == 'no' && $("input[name='owner']:checked").val() === undefined) {
      $('.selectOwner').addClass('error-higlight');
    } else {
      $('.selectOwner').removeClass('error-higlight');
    }
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectOwner').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected != '') {
      $('.selectOwner').removeClass('error-higlight');
    } else {
      $('.selectOwner').addClass('error-higlight');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field text-left">
  <label for="owner1" class="text-left owner">
    <input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" />
     <span class="overlay-color"></span>Working</label>
</div>
<div class="field text-left">
  <label for="owner2" class="text-left owner">
    <input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" />
     <span class="overlay-color"></span>Jobless</label>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
  <label for="Yes" class="text-left">Yes</label>
  <input class="selectStatus" name="status" id="Yes" type="radio" value="yes" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <label for="No" class="text-left">No</label>
  <input class="selectStatus" name="status" id="No" type="radio" value="no" />
</div>

<style>
  .error-higlight {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217, 83, 80, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217, 83, 80, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217, 83, 80, 1);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: @Zain Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge the two functions together and create an if statement that questions where selectStatus == no && selectOwner == ' '.

With what you have at the moment, it is only checking each input exclusively so it is not considering the value of the other input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you were looking for:

```
<div class="field text-left">
    <label for="owner1" class="text-left owner">
    <input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" value="working" />
     <span class="overlay-color"></span>Working</label>
</div>
<div class="field text-left">
    <label for="owner2" class="text-left owner">
    <input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" value="jobless" />
     <span class="overlay-color"></span>Jobless</label>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="Yes" class="text-left">Yes</label>
    <input class="selectStatus" name="status" id="Yes" type="radio" value="yes" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="No" class="text-left">No</label>
    <input class="selectStatus" name="status" id="No" type="radio" value="no"  />  
</div>

<style>
.error-higlight{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217,83,80,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217,83,80,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(217,83,80,1);
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=status]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'no' && $('input[name=owner]:checked').val() == undefined) {
            $('.selectOwner').addClass('error-higlight');
        } else {
            $('.selectOwner').removeClass('error-higlight');                    
        }
    });

    $('input[name=owner]').click(function () {
        if ($('input[name=status]:checked').val() !== undefined) {
            $('.selectOwner').removeClass('error-higlight');
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```